# How do I bundle library files for use in branches?

Tags: version-control, svn, branching

I work at a company which has it's source code managed using subversion. Our code base is huge (800MB) but we want to work with branching. For what I noticed is that when branching, SVN just duplicates **every** file which makes it almost impossible to branch because of the space.

I would like to separate our library and other not often changed files, so it can be loaded in each branch and stored only once. How can I *structure our repository* so that branching doesn't copy every single file in the repository?

I was looking at `svn:externals`, but I don't know if that's the way to go.

Comment: I'm more of a git guy myself and I couldn't believe this to be true either. It's weird because the files in my `branches` folder and `trunk` folder aren't hardlinks they are actual files which take up actual space. Maybe this is because the svn host I'm using (beanstalkapp) does something weird?

Comment: @snowman If you check out the root, you get one directory per branch on the *client*. I think that's where the OP's confusion comes from. But AFAIR you can check out individual branches.

Comment: Yes I got that, and I would understand if these files were symlinks to original files. But the total size of my project folder is **much** bigger than one branch folder for example

Comment: Oops sorry, mind pointing me where to ask this question? It's kind of a big issue.

Comment: Why is it a big issue? As others have pointed out, the space is only consumed on the client, not the server. And there are many techniques for minimizing that space, the simplest being to delete the branches once you've merged them to trunk. You can also use `--depth` and `--set-depth` to control what gets pulled to the client. Or you can create an `archived-branches` directory where you `svn mv` branches after merge (although, really, deleting them is far better).

Comment: @kdgregory: 800MB may not be such a big issue nowadays, but if someone branches the full trunk, I guess it will still need some time for a full checkout and a full compile in a separate working copy. So I would be interested in an answer, too, for example, if one wants to branch just one module, lets say of <100K size in source, and has the full trunk in his working directory, if there is a good approach for avoiding to have the full 800MB to checkout twice on the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some caveats:

1. You really shouldn't be storing libraries in your source-control system. Especially third-party libraries. Depending on the language and tools that you're using, there are a lot of ways to avoid doing so, but that's another question.
2. Recognize that the Subversion repository uses the equivalent of links internally, so the only time a file is actually duplicated is when it's changed. If you commit a file in version 100 of the repository, every branch based on that version will reference the same file (unless and until you commit a new version).
3. You *don't* want Subversion to create symlinks on the client. You want each branch to be self-contained, so that you don't accidentally change a shared file. However, be aware that Subversion will manage symlinks that *you* create.

With those in mind, and with the goal of moving toward a world where you don;t keep your libraries in the *source* repository, I recommend creating separate directories at the top of your repository:

```
/libraries
/project-1
    /trunk
    /tags
    /branches
```

This is one of the under-appreciated features of Subversion: you can check out any arbitrary subtree of the repository into any arbitrary directory on your local filesystem.

So, how do you deal with separation of libraries and source? That again depends on your language and tools. It can be as simple (and ugly, and barely maintainable) as a `lib` directory in your project that contains symlinks back to the `libraries` directory.

Better is to use a build tool that gets its library references from a configuration file. This will let you easily add libraries into the repository, and lets different project versions use different sets of libraries.

Comment: "You really shouldn't be storing libraries in your source-control system" - I think that is not what you really meant. You mean not to store shared libraries in the same *tree* or *repository* as other source code, but still in your SCS, right?

Comment: @DocBrown - no, I meant exactly what I said. In my view, libraries are _dependencies_ used by your source code, and _artifacts_ produced from your source code, but they are not source code in themselves. You may have a need to store libraries-as-dependencies in a locally-managed repository, but I believe that even there a source code management system with its "forget nothing" design is inappropriate.

Comment: If updating a dependency can break software, then there is at least some potential value in having that dependency in source control, especially if you have continuous integration. Whether it's a net positive or not varies, but I find that in any project which requires "building" the final deliverable, there's usually at least one dependency for which it makes sense to have a "local" copy.

Comment: @Ixrec - "local" copy, sure, but why in the source control repo? Perhaps I've been spoiled by the Java ecosystem, where Maven Central has been a reliable resource for ten years or so. But even when I was writing C code back in the 80s, we kept our source separate from our builds.

Comment: @kdgregory Good point about Maven. I'm used to environments that are a little less robust and self-contained when it comes to dependency management, and some dependencies that are utterly nightmarish to build (blame it on C++).

Comment: @kdgregory: when we talk about libraries, we do not talk about third party libs here mainly (reread what the OP wrote). We talk about libs the OPs organization owns, and their source code. Whereelse shall they store that source code when not in a source code control system? In a zip file on a network share? And in your answer, you suggest to store the libs in the SVN repo under a /libraries path (contradictory to what you wrote in 1, which means "do not use SVN for libs"). You surely meant something different.

Comment: @DocBrown - I repeat: I wrote exactly what I meant to write. While I don't believe that artifacts and source code belong together, that does not mean that they _can't_ be stored in the same repo. I just think alternatives are better. Feel free to post your own recommendations, I don't feel like getting into a debate in the comments.